# Magmi - Issue uploading more than one media_gallery image

Tags: php, magento, magmi

i have been using Magmi for a long time and have never had issues until i started using the media_gallery column.

When using this column the first image is always imported. Any subsequent images appended by a ";" are throwing an error "cannot be found in image path".

Here is an example upload:

```
    sku     media_gallery
    00090   00090.pt01.jpg
    01321   01321.alt01.jpg;01321-pt02.jpg;01321-pt03.jpg;01321-alt02.jpg;0131-alt03.jpg;01321-lf.jpg
    01322   01322.alt01.jpg;01322.alt02.jpg;01322.alt03.jpg;01322.lf.jpg
    01327   01327.alt01.jpg;01327.pt02.jpg;01327.lf.jpg
    01417   01417.lf.jpg
    01433   01433.pt01.jpg
    2450001 2450001.pt01.jpg
    27730301    27730301.pt02.jpg;27730301.pt03.jpg
    31321   31321.pt02.jpg;31321.pt03.jpg;31321.alt02.jpg;31321.alt03.jpg
    31325   31325.pt02.jpg;31325.pt03.jpg
    46505   46505.pt02.jpg;46505.pt03.jpg
    52021   52021.pt02.jpg
    52251   52251.pt02.jpg
    58529

    64413   64413.pt02.jpg
    64750   64750.pt02.jpg
    64751   64751.alt01.jpg
    64755   64755.alt01.jpg;64755.pt02.jpg;64755.alt02.jpg;64755.alt03.jpg
    64906   64906.pt02.jpg;64906.alt02.jpg
    65114   65114.alt01.jpg;65114.pt02.jpg;65114.alt02.jpg
    65123   65123.pt02.jpg
    7732001 7732001.alt01.jpg;7732001.pt02.jpg;7732001.pt03.jpg;7732001.alt02.jpg;7732001.alt03.jpg
    7732301 7732301.alt01.jpg;7732301.pt02.jpg;7732301.pt03.jpg;7732301.alt02.jpg
    7791301 7791301.pt02.jpg
    7792001 7792001.alt01.jpg;7792001.pt02.jpg;7792001.pt03.jpg;7792001.alt02.jpg
    78030   78030.pt01.jpg
    7805101 7805101.lf.jpg;7805101.pt01.jpg
    8440501 8440501.pt02.jpg;8440501.pt03.jpg;8440501.alt02.jpg;8440501.alt03.jpg;8440501.pt01.jpg
    90072   90072.pt01.jpg
    93210301    93210301.pt01.jpg
    99110   99110.pt01.jpg
```

`</pre>`

(Commas left out between columens but are there in import)

In the above example anything with one image imports perfectly. A sku with multiple images only imports the first one.

I am following all the standard rules such as using a semi-colon in between image names. I tried different enconding formats

The images reside in a remote path:

http://example.com/images/

I have spent many hours on this and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitely define the remote path on your media_gallery column for each image:

```
http://example.com/images/xxxxx.jpg;http://example.com/images/yyyyy.jpg;
```

or if you are using the latest magmi git , you might use the new "Remote Image root" field to define a remote server base url (http://example.com/images/) where all those images could be found.

Comment: Hello dweeves, thanks so much for the extension.I will attempt defining the paths explicitly however  i am using the current version with the option to add a remote url path. Which is why my paths in the example above are just the trailing image names. ITs weird because like i said the importer always recognizes the first image but not any subsequent ones.

Comment: Hi Dweeves, maybe not the correct place to post it but i spent a few hours on the latest version and cant get an upload to work. Once the new version was installed and i run an import i get the following blank error: "1 not found -" and the eror in trace.txt: ************************************
 not found
*************************************
/plugins/base/datasources/csv/magmi_csvdatasource.php:121 - Magmi_CSVReader->checkCSV

Comment: Just to be clear all settings are correct and i triple checked the paths to my remote csv's for upload.

Comment: there was a bug in the commit that was fixed just after (in fact i forgot to commit some changes). please do a git pull & all should be operational

Comment: Sadly same exact error no matter what settings i use or change i get the following (Im on magento community  1.9) : "1 error(s) found Hide Details
1 not found -" With no additional info

Comment: could you send me the trace.txt file by mail so that i can have an idea on what could go wrong on your setup ?

Comment: Yes sure. What is the mail to reach you on?

Comment: i won't communicate it here. but click on "Dweeves" (in the header, provided to the community by Dweeves) on the magmi UI, it's a link to my email.

Comment: Sent i appreciate the help